# Why do I get "missing os" after installing with minimal cd?

Tags: 13.04

I needed to install ubuntu from a minimal cd because I wanted to setup raid. However I get "missing os" when booting from the harddisk containing the root partition (I did not create a separate boot partition). Luckily it boots from the disk when I try to boot from the usb pen (yes I checked, I am not booting from that usb pen).

The harddisk containing the root partition has two partitions, root and swap. /home and /var are on different volumes.

Interestingly there the partition program left about about 1MB in the beginning of that drive although I asked for the partition to be placed and the beginning. This space is left there even if I try to add a partition for the bios boot area. I dont think that shows up when partitioning with 12.04.

Ive tried installing a couple of times now, using different setups on the harddisk containing the root partition. How do I setup boot correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I on a previous install had put a GPT partition table on the disk that the formatting tool did not recognize. In order to fix it I had to delete the partition table on all the harddisks using gparted before installing.